# Partial HAML templating in Ruby without Rails

Tags: ruby, haml, templating

I really don’t need the overhead of Rails for my very small project, so I’m trying to achieve this just using just plain Ruby and HAML.

I want to include another HAML file inside my HAML template. But I haven’t found a good—or really usable—way of doing this.

For example, I have these two HAML files:

documents.haml

```
%html
 %body
  = include(menu.haml) body
  %article …
```

menu.haml

```
%ul
 %li
  %a whatever …
```

Include is obviously not the way to go here. But it does a nice job describing what I’m trying to achieve in this example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've done this before, just for a quick-and-dirty template producer.  The easiest way is to just render the HAML inside the parent object:

```
%p some haml that's interesting
= Haml::Engine.new('%p this is a test').render
%p some more template
```

You'll more than likely want to build some methods to make this easier--a couple of helper methods.  Maybe you write one called render_file that takes a filename as an argument.  That method might look something like:

```
def render_file(filename)
  contents = File.read(filename)
  Haml::Engine.new(contents).render
end
```

Then, your template would look more like:

```
%p some template
= render_file('some_filename.haml')
%p more template
```

Note, you will probably need to pass self to the original Haml::Engine render so that it knows how to find your render_file method.

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I was looking for! I appreciate it, and thanks for the suggested helper methods.

Comment: You bet.  It's nice when something I've done can be useful to someone else.  Good luck.

Comment: How to include the helper method to the haml template?

Comment: I'm using the HAML compiler without Rails, I created a file called hamlHelper.rb like this https://gist.github.com/mustafah/b2fba950916457339505 and used the require argument while invoking the compiler " haml -r hamlHelper.rb myfile.haml myfile.html"

Answer (score 23):

I totally recommend the [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt) gem for these things. It provides a standard interface for rendering many different template langages with the same API, lets you set custom scope and locals, lets you use yield, and is robust and fast. Sinatra is using it for templates.

Example:

```
require 'haml'
require 'tilt'

template = Tilt.new('path/to/file.haml')
# => #<Tilt::HAMLTemplate @file="path/to/file.haml" ...>
layout   = Tilt.new('path/to/layout.haml')

output = layout.render { template.render }
```

This lets you `yield` inside the layout to get the rendered template, just like Rails. As for partials, David already described a simple and nice way to go.

But actually, if what you're writing is going to be served over HTTP, i suggest you take a look at [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), which already provides templating, and has the simplest request routing you could imagine.

Answer (score 3):

I've had great success just using the instructions posted by [David Richards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/177363/david-richards) in a concatenated way, without variables, like this:

`= Haml::Engine.new(File.read('/Volumes/Project/file_to_include.haml')).render`

There's obviously a more elegant way. But for someone who just wants to include one or two files, this should work nicely. It's a drawback that all base files using these includes have to be recompiled after some changes to the latter. It might be worthwile to just use php include if the environment allows that.

Answer (score 0):

```
def render_file(filename)
  contents = File.read('views/'+filename)
  Haml::Engine.new(contents).render
end
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

(Adding this semi-redundant answer to show how one might incorporate the techniques from other answers.)

Include something like this in your setup code to monkey-patch the Haml library.

```
module Haml::Helpers
  def render_haml(filename)
    contents = File.read(Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "templates", filename))
    Haml::Engine.new(contents).render
  end
end
```

Then in your Haml file

```
.foo
= render_haml('partial.haml')
.bar
```

Obviously this is a Rails-ish example (because I wanted to use HAML in my asset pipeline instead of as views)... You will want to replace `Rails.root.join(...)` with a way to find `filename` in your project's templates or partials directory.