# HAML render in Prepros App - bug or just me?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compiler-errors, haml

I can't get including partial files in HAML to work.

I have a code from basic HAML tests

```
# file: partial_layout.haml
%h1 Partial layout used with for block:
= render :layout => 'layout_for_partial' do
  %p Some content within a layout
```

And second file

```
# file: _layout_for_partial.haml
.partial-layout
  %h2 This is inside a partial layout
  = yield
```

So i click a compile button in Prepros App...

```
Exception on line 2: undefined method `render' for #<Object:0x2a196c8>
  Use --trace for backtrace.

D:\Download\haml-master\haml-master\test\templates\partial_layout.haml
```

This should be basic HAML function. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Partials are a Ruby on Rails feature, not a Haml feature. It looks like you're using this outside of Rails, so the `render` method is not going to be available. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436769/partial-haml-templating-in-ruby-without-rails for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me.

```
!!!
:javascript
    alert('oi'); 
%asp:TextBox#teste  
    = Haml::Engine.new(File.read(File.dirname(__FILE__)+'\include_file.haml')).render
#outro
    = File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

Pay atention that if you make any changes in the included file with this techinique Prepros dont "automagically" updates the file that use the included file. This needed to be done by your owns hands.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but if you switch to Jade (which is very similar to HAML) it supports `include` (for partials) and `extends` for child templates, just using Prepos.