# How do I include a haml file in haml?

Tags: sinatra, haml

How do I include a haml file in haml? It isn't described in the docs.
([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436769/partial-haml-templating-in-ruby-without-rails) talks about inserting parameterized templates but that isn't what I'm looking for.)

I'm using Sinatra but I should hope it doesn't matter.

Is inserting plain HTML any easier?

Comment: if you are not looking for parameterized templates then what? what do you need it for?

Comment: Code/template organization and not repeating myself. I have something that should appear in multiple templates (scripts, header, footer, etc)

Comment: Does a template *have to* change depending on parameters?

Comment: no it is possible to use paramaterized templates but it is a bit tedious to repeat the imports on every page. thus the suggested answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you want is a layout template. I made this myself a while ago with sinatra and it is really handy. Put the common stuff you want in `views/layout.haml` - this will likely be a full HTML document with head and body and all the things that will be the same on a given page.

```
%head
  -# some head tags here
%body
  -# header menu here
  = yield
  -# a bit footer here
```

The yield part is where you want to have the things that differ between pages. (It uses the built in Ruby method `yield` to execute a block that has been passed in. If you are familiar with Ruby you know what that means - owtherwise don't think about it too much until you have something that works.)

Then in your sinatra code wher you call haml you just do as you normally do and sinatra will pick up the layout file for you.

```
haml :specific_page
```

If you want to be more specific about where your layout is you can pass in a named layout:

```
haml :specific_page, layout: :other_layout
```

and it will look for `other_layout.haml` instead of layout. You can also turn off layouting with:

```
haml :specific_page, layout: false
```

I think this it what you are after. It actually is in the sinatra docs but not in the section about haml. It works like this regardless of what templating engine you use.

Comment: There's very little reuse between pages so I really would have preferred a %include directive but it seems it doesn't exist. Your answer is the next best thing I guess.

Comment: I sort of like this approach for layouts. :-) Why don't you like the `render` method? http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Engine.html#render-instance_method . You don't have to parameterize it if you don't want to.

Comment: render seems to be what I was looking for, thanks! I didn't read the other question carefully enough.